# Can I export my users' third party cookies such as those from Yandex to Google Ads?

Tags: google, advertising, cookie, export

I have been collecting cookies by different services like Yandex, Mautic, Facebook pixel etc. Now I need to share/import these Cookies to Google for make remarketing from my WEB by Google Ads.

Example: For a long time I collect data only with Yandex. I have 10k users that haven't cleaned those cookies. So I can always see when they come back to my website. I want to migrate to Google Ads for my users. Can I export Yandex cookies to Google ads for make remarketing campaigns?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand your main objective is to re-target your website visitors. It doesn't really matter from which source they first came to your website as long as they came and if you had google analytics installed you can re-target them. There is no need to do anything with the cookies.

In your Google Ads account you have to go to:

> Tools&Settings -> Audience Manager (Shared Library)

Then click on ADD (blue circle with +) and then choose website visitors. 
That way you can create an audience consisting of people who visited your website in the past from any source (Yandex, Facebook etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer m8. I just tried this and it's looks strange. I did test with 3 WEBs (With only Google Analytics, With only Yandex, With both of them) and all 3 times got the same results.

Google tell me that I have 0 Cookies for these webs for create this audience. So it's just doesn't work for WEB with GA also https://prnt.sc/q00x4t